# how to use of Hash map/dictionary to fetch values from data frame? faster alternate to for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dictionary, hash, dataframe

I have data frame consisting of tick data of options for the day. I want to evaluate max trade for each ticker for every minute. I am using for loop but as I have 3000+ tickers and 9600000+ trades,its turning out to be really slow.
Is there any way to fetch row values from dataframe for each ticker using map/dictionary/hash table?

Again objective is :
max trade in every minute for every ticker for that day
optionData --->ticker--->Minute data---> max trade in that minute

Given:
optionData as data frame with columns like date,time,tickerSymbols,TradeVolume,Delta,iVol

Comment: Did you try `dplyr`?  `optionData %>% group_by(tickerSymbols, date, time) %>% filter(TradeVolume == max(TradeVolume))`

Comment: No I havent. let me check that out. Thank you so much maloneypatr

Comment: Yeah, that may not work if your time is more granular than minute.  But, you can convert times to minute using lubridate.  I'll write the code I'd use as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you install and load the necessary packages.  If they're already installed, don't worry about running the `install.pacakges` line.  It's commented out in this example.

```
#install.packages(c('dplyr', 'lubridate'))
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

So, this should do the trick if your time variable is more granular than minute.  (Like it includes seconds, etc.)

```
optionData %>%
  mutate(minute = minute(time),
         hour = hour(time)) %>%
  group_by(tickerSymbols, date, hour, minute) %>%
  filter(TradeVolume == max(TradeVolume))
```

This should do the trick if your time variable is already representative of minute.

```
optionData %>%
  group_by(tickerSymbols, date, time) %>%
  filter(TradeVolume == max(TradeVolume))
```

Both answers are assuming that `TradeVolume` is where we can find the max trade that you're looking for.